# Can't run Linux "awk" command in script from PHP

Tags: php, linux, awk, pid, cut

I have the shell script "test.sh":

```
  #!/system/bin/sh

  PID=$(ps | grep logcat | grep root |grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
  echo "Using awk: $PID"


  PID=$(ps | grep logcat | grep root |grep -v grep | cut -d " " -f 7 )
  echo "Using cut: $PID"
```

When I run the script from PHP:

```
exec("su -c sh /path/to/my/script/test.sh");
```

I got this output:

```
Using awk:
Using cut: 6512
```

So "cut" command is work but "awk" command doesn't when I run the script from PHP, but when I run it from terminal:

```
# sh test.sh
```

I can get both awk and cut work fine! This how look like the output of "ps":

```
USER      PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS   WCHAN       PC         NAME
root      6512  5115  3044   1108  poll_sched b6e4bb0c S logcat
```

Do I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to **debug** first

You said

> So "cut" command is work but "awk" command doesn't when I run the
>   script from PHP, but when I run it from terminal:

I wonder how ?

actually throws error like below, in CLI

```
$ php -r 'exec("su -c sh /path/to/my/script/test.sh");'
su: user /path/to/my/script/test.sh does not exist
```

You first need below syntax while debugging code

```
// basic :  stdin (0) stdout (1) stderr (2)

exec('your_command 2>&1', $output, $return_status);

// to see the response from your command
// su: user /path/to/my/script/test.sh does not exist
print_r($output);
```

> **Remember** :
>
> - `su` gives you root permissions but it does not change the `PATH` variable and current working directory.
> - The operating system assumes that, in the absence of a username, the
>     user wants to change to a root session, and thus the user is prompted
>     for the root password

```
[akshay@localhost Desktop]$ su
Password: 
[root@localhost Desktop]# pwd
/home/akshay/Desktop
[root@localhost Desktop]# exit
exit

[akshay@localhost Desktop]$ su -
Password: 
[root@localhost ~]# pwd
/root
```

**Solution:**

You should allow executing your script without password prompt ( don't use `su` use `sudo` )

To allow apache user to execute your script and some commands you may make entry like below in `/etc/sudoers`

```
# which awk => give you awk path
# same use in your script also, or else set path variable 
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/script/test.sh, /bin/cut, /usr/bin/awk
```

So it becomes :

```
// assuming your script is executable 
exec("sudo /path/to/my/script/test.sh 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, the output of $output and $return_status are "Array" and "0" respectively which mean no issue! I forgot to mention that I am using Android Linux (I ssh to android by SSHelper app), no sudo command only su. For PHP I am using KSWEB app.